# How to convert int to signed char?

Tags: python

Let's say I have integer x (-128 <= x <= 127). How to convert x to signed char?

I did like this. But I couldn't.

```
>>> x = -1
>>> chr(x)
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

Comment: Python has no signed character type ... What are you planning on doing with it?

Comment: @mgilson I want to save int as a type of signed char. So that I can read it from C.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant from "read it from C", but you can do:  `import ctypes;x=ctypes.c_int32(-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Python, there aren't really any borders between `signed`, `unsigned`, `char`, `int`, `long`, etc.  However, if your aim is to serialize data to use with a C module, function, or whatever, you can use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to pack and unpack data.  `b`, for example, packs data as a `signed char` type.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('bbb', 1, -2, 4)
b'\x01\xfe\x04'
```

If you're directly talking to a C function, [use `ctypes` types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) as Ashwin suggests; when you pass them Python translates them as appropriate and piles them on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because `x` is not between 0 and 256.

`chr` must be given an `int` between 0 and 256.

Comment: @MattDMo From https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr: `The argument must be in the range [0..255], inclusive`.

Comment: @MattDMo The error in the OP implies that he is **not** using Py3.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `chr()` does not convert an int into a signed char (which Python doesn't have anyway). `chr()` returns a Unicode string having the ordinal value of the inputted int.

```
>>> chr(77)
'M'
>>> chr(690)
'ʲ'
```

The input can be a number in any supported base, not just decimal:

```
>>> chr(0xBAFF)
'뫿'
```

Note: In Python 2, the int must be between 0 and 255, and will output a standard (non-Unicode) string. `unichr()` in Py2 behaves as above.

Comment: Somewhat strange there isn't a `from six.moves import chr` if those two are one and the same.

Comment: @Ashwini correct. I think in Py3 most of the time :) I updated my answer to address its functions in **both** versions